# Какой View является родителем (parent) корневого элемента xml-разметки?

Tags: android, android-layout, view

В [книге](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/141049718/) (*в русском переводе*) на странице 39 в описании обычной разметки `xml` утверждается следующее:

> В корневом элементе LinearLayout атрибуты ширины и высоты равны
>   match_parent. Элемент LinearLayout является корневым, но у него все
>   равно есть родитель — **представление Android для размещения иерархии
>   представлений вашего приложения.**

В оригинале (*Android Programming - The "Big Nerd Ranch" Guide* (*3 ed.*)) этот же абзац:

> For the root LinearLayout, the value of both the height and width
>   attributes is match_parent. The LinearLayout is the root element, but
>   it still has a parent – the view that Android provides for your app’s
>   view hierarchy to live in.

Интересно узнать подробнее о представлении (как я понимаю, это перевод слова "View") который содержит в себе иерархию View приложения вместе с корневым элементом. Что из себя представляет этот `View`? Взаимодействует ли Разработчик как-то с ним?

Comment: В студии Tools-Android-Layout inspector увидите иерархию вплоть до DecorView

Answer (score 9):

Попробуем чуть чуть разобраться, а то глядеть просто на иерархию `Tools-Android-Layout inspector` как-то не интересно.

Итак: - (*рис. 1*)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [Activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) — это компонент приложения, который выдает экран, и с
>   которым пользователи могут взаимодействовать для выполнения каких-либо
>   действий, например набрать номер телефона, сделать фото, отправить
>   письмо или просмотреть карту. Каждой операции присваивается окно для
>   прорисовки соответствующего пользовательского интерфейса. Обычно окно
>   отображается во весь экран, однако его размер может быть меньше, и оно
>   может размещаться поверх других окон (*[отсюда](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html)*).

Имеется абстрактный класс [Window](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html). (*далее вольный перевод*)

> Абстрактный базовый класс для определения поведения и внешнего вида
>   окна верхнего уровня (`top-level`). Экземпляр этого класса должен
>   использоваться как представление верхнего уровня, добавленное в
>   оконный менеджер (`window manager`). Он предоставляет стандартные
>   политики пользовательского интерфейса, такие как фон, область
>   заголовка, обработка ключевых слов по умолчанию и т.д.
>
> Единственной существующей реализацией этого абстрактного класса
>   является `android.view.PhoneWindow`, которую вы должны создать при
>   необходимости `Window`.

[Находим](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/696cba573e651b0e4f18a4718627c8ccecb3bda0/policy/src/com/android/internal/policy/impl/PhoneWindow.java) `android.view.PhoneWindow`.

```
public class PhoneWindow extends Window implements MenuBuilder.Callback {...
```

В нем имеются перегруженные методы `setContentView`, некоторые из которых, как я понимаю, определяют создание `DecorView`. А именно, через метод `installDecor()`.

```
...
    if (mContentParent == null) {
        installDecor();
    }
...
```

Внутри `installDecor()` определяется `mDecor`. Об этой переменной в строке 111

```
// This is the top-level view of the window, containing the window decor.
private DecorView mDecor;
```

Теперь о `DecorView`. (*рис. 2*) [Воспользуемся](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector.html) `Tools > Android > Layout Inspector`

1. View Tree: Иерархия `view` в макете.
2. Screenshot: Скриншот устройства с видимыми границами для каждого `view`.
3. Properties Table: макетные свойства для выбранного `view`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На рисунке видно где в иерархии(1) находится `DecorView`. `DecorView` - реальный корень иерархии Views Окна (Window).

Реализация промежуточных `views` между `DecorView` и корневым элементом нашего макета может различаться в зависимости от версии `Android`.
Для сравнения. Вот так выглядит иерархия `view` [в статье от 2009 года](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/03/window-backgrounds-ui-speed.html).(*рис. 3*)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так в [книге](https://play.google.com/store/books/details?id=aaXWDQAAQBAJ&rdid=book-aaXWDQAAQBAJ&rdot=1&source=gbs_vpt_read&pcampaignid=books_booksearch_viewport) 2016 года (*стр 53*) (*рис. 4*)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`DecorView` содержит по умолчанию фон `Activity`, определяемой темой (`theme`). Часто данный фон перекрывается фоном нашего макета (`layout`). `DecorView` рисуется в первую очередь. Фон можно как удалить, так и поменять с использованием темы:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    </style>
</resources>



<resources>
   <style name="Theme.NoBackground" parent="android:Theme">
     <item name="android:windowBackground">
     @drawable/background</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

Программно:

[getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()](http://d.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setBackgroundDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))